# How to draw lines and put objects relative to other lines

Tags: tables, graphics, diagrams

I'm trying to draw a simple line, and at the end of that line include a table. I would like to do it without having to compute myself the position where the table needs to be drawn. How can I do that?

many thanks

Comment: perhaps using `tikz`: `% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \node[minimum width=3cm] (b) at (1,0){\begin{tabular}{cc}1&2\\3&4\end{tabular}};
  \draw (a)--(b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @cmhughes: an answer? (it seems we exchanged the usual roles `;)` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the wonderfully versatile and popular [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) package; there are lots of way to do it, but one such method follows.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex 
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0); 
    \node[minimum width=3cm] (b) at (1,0){\begin{tabular}{cc}1&2\\3&4\end{tabular}}; 
    \draw (a)--(b); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `tikz` ;)  (for a change)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \rule[0.6ex]{1in}{1pt}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1&2\\
    3&4
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Then why's `tikz` loaded? `:P`

Comment: @KevinC I blame it on cmhughes as I copied his code. But in reality, `\usepackage{tikz}` is a die hard habit (which my brain refuses to delete) :)

Comment: sneaky :) you currently have 1 vote, and I have 3, yet your answer appears above mine... not at all a big deal - I'm just curious?....

Comment: @cmhughes hihi! I were thinking that you won't see this ;)

Comment: lol :) can't believe you posted an answer *without* `tikz` :)

Comment: @cmhughes Some times I do. :)